# Can I link to a comment on StackExchange sites to reference a users comment in an answer?

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request

I was reading [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/110258/87457) today on Security.StackEchange and as I was reading through the [top answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/110262/87457) I saw a comment which had 25 up votes that actually made sense as a very good answer in itself

I would like to post this as an answer as I think it is the best response to the question but obviously this isn't my answer. So I would like to post the answer and link to the comment to reference the user who made it.

Is it possible to link to a comment? and if not what should I do in this situation?

Comment: [Yes you can](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314526/can-i-link-to-a-comment-on-stackexchange-sites-to-reference-a-users-comment-in-a#comment293488_314526). Take the address of the time field.

Comment: Click on the "X ago" on a comment, then you can copy the url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this.

Copy the contents of the comment and reference it (to grab the link of the comment, [click on the comment timestamp](https://i.gyazo.com/862f8fb6285798a4aafa120f20bd388d.gif)). When you post the answer, make sure you [tick the Community Wiki button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IErTV.png).

Read: [What are community wiki posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)

Comment: @Hd Just out of interest, what does the `Community Wiki` button represent? It's a feature I have not come across yet

Comment: Usually [when I've copied someone's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34433987/php-how-to-read-word-document-with-text-and-images/34434718#34434718) and put it as an answer, I [use community wiki](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) so not to "rep steal", which can anger users.